# TimeoutException on a WebClient call while using JDK 11

Tags: reactor-netty

There was an TimeoutException as shown below while using JDK 11 for WebClient:

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 60000ms in 'source(MonoDefer)' (and no fallback has been configured)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.handleTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar!/:3.4.24]
```

However, if JDK 8 were used then it works fine and no above TimeoutException with the same test case.
The application is built by using Spring Boot V2.7.5 with "spring-boot-starter-webflux". Here is the version of "reactor-netty-http" in the application:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-netty-http</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.24</version>
</dependency>
```

Here are the observations:

1. If idle enough time ( aobut 30 seconds ) after the call of a WebClient then below connnection was closed:

   ```
   2022-11-14 11:17:47.773 DEBUG 7600 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [3d257d24, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:64172 - R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] READ COMPLETE
   2022-11-14 11:18:17.264 DEBUG 7600 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [3d257d24, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:64172 - R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] READ COMPLETE
   2022-11-14 11:18:17.265 DEBUG 7600 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [3d257d24, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:64172 ! R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] USER_EVENT: SslCloseCompletionEvent(java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)
   2022-11-14 11:18:17.265 DEBUG 7600 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [3d257d24, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:64172 ! R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] INACTIVE
   2022-11-14 11:18:17.265 DEBUG 7600 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [3d257d24, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:64172 ! R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] UNREGISTERED
   ```

   As you can see, the HttpClient on the thread 'ctor-http-nio-3' was closed and unregistered after about 30 seconds with a SslCloseCompletionEvent(java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException).
2. Then try to use the webclient again by sending a request. Here is an output which was successfully:

   ```
   2022-11-14 11:18:59.542 DEBUG 7600 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [476de49d] REGISTERED
   2022-11-14 11:18:59.630 DEBUG 7600 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [476de49d] CONNECT: nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443
   2022-11-14 11:18:59.743 DEBUG 7600 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [476de49d, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:64197 - R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] ACTIVE
   2022-11-14 11:18:59.849 DEBUG 7600 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [476de49d, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:64197 - R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] READ COMPLETE
   2022-11-14 11:18:59.858 DEBUG 7600 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [476de49d, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:64197 - R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] USER_EVENT: SslHandshakeCompletionEvent(SUCCESS)
   2022-11-14 11:18:59.860 DEBUG 7600 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [476de49d-1, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:64197 - R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] WRITE: 2023B 
   .
   .
   .
   ```

   As you can see a new connection was registered on a new thread 'ctor-http-nio-4'. The call was successfully.
3. However if the connection was closed successfully - SslCloseCompletionEvent(SUCCESS) and unregistered. Here is an output:

   ```
   2022-11-14 09:10:41.295 DEBUG 21332 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [9a6b8e52, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:56897 - R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] CLOSE
   2022-11-14 09:10:41.303 DEBUG 21332 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [9a6b8e52, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:56897 ! R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] USER_EVENT: SslCloseCompletionEvent(SUCCESS)
   2022-11-14 09:10:41.303 DEBUG 21332 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [9a6b8e52, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:56897 ! R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] READ COMPLETE
   2022-11-14 09:10:41.303 DEBUG 21332 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [9a6b8e52, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:56897 ! R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] INACTIVE
   2022-11-14 09:10:41.303 DEBUG 21332 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [9a6b8e52, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:56897 ! R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] UNREGISTERED
   ```
4. Then try to use the webclient again by sending a request which is registered an new connection. Here is an output:

   ```
   2022-11-14 09:11:32.362 DEBUG 21332 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [ad2bc21d] REGISTERED
   2022-11-14 09:11:32.424 DEBUG 21332 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [ad2bc21d] CONNECT: nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443
   2022-11-14 09:11:32.528 DEBUG 21332 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [ad2bc21d, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:56922 - R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] ACTIVE
   2022-11-14 09:11:32.970 DEBUG 21332 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [ad2bc21d, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:56922 - R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] READ COMPLETE
   2022-11-14 09:11:33.063 DEBUG 21332 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [ad2bc21d, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:56922 - R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] READ COMPLETE
   2022-11-14 09:11:33.063 DEBUG 21332 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [ad2bc21d, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:56922 - R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] READ COMPLETE
   2022-11-14 09:11:33.165 DEBUG 21332 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [ad2bc21d, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:56922 - R:nnctj2prxc4t.apps.internal.xxxxx.net/xx.xx.xx.xx:443] USER_EVENT: SslHandshakeCompletionEvent(SUCCESS)
   .
   .
   .

   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 60000ms in 'source(MonoDefer)' (and no fallback has been configured)
           at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.handleTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar!/:3.4.24]
   ```

   As you can see, after the connection was closed successfully and unregistered then later call will result TimeoutException with a new registered connection.

Above issue occurred while using JDK 11 (zulu-jdk11.0.14) only. If use JDK 8 (zulu8.61.0.18-sa-jdk8.0.331) then everything is working fine.

I tried to use the same appliation with different JDK 8 and JDK 11. Using JDK 8, there is no issue for WebClient to connect to the REST API and get the data back successfully.
However, I tried to use JDK 11 then I got ReadTimeoutException.

The Application is built by using Spring Boot 2.7.5 which is the latest version. It is using WebClient to connect the REST API server. The built target is Java 8.

Even I tried to build the applicaiton with target Java 11 and running it in Java 11 but still getting the same error.

How can I solve this?